# Simple SELECT SQL statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
SELECT user FROM members WHERE admin=1;

SELECT user FROM members WHERE id=1;
```

The first query does not work because there's an error in my syntax. The second works but they are virtually identical. Both 'admin' and 'id' are INT(11), but 'id' is the primary key and set to auto-increment. What's wrong here?

The error I receive is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin=1' at line 1

Comment: show you DB Table

Comment: @JonathonOgden the datatype of admin column is INT.  This is the exact error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin=1' at line 1

Comment: you need to post the PHP for this since you tagged as such. Your error doesn't support what you posted in comments. That, or see an answer posted below.

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to run a multi-query (in php), tell me I'm right. Ping me, I'm not staring at this anymore than I already have and to try and help you out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No I'm only trying to run the first query. I ran the second just to check if my syntax is correct. I don't receive any syntax errors with my second query.

Comment: sorry but I can't help with what I don't know/see. Again, ask the guy who gave you an answer below. Comments stand to keep growing and growing until we get to the heart of the matter and stand to lose a lot of time; not just mine but yours as well. I wish you all the best with this one, truly. I have been through the ringer too many times on questions like this, where we/I ask about relevance to php etc. Don't feel offended by this, I'm just being honest.

Comment: I revisited this question and you totally defaced it http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40661191/4. The error is clear; mysql reserved word `group` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html. I rolled it back to a previous revision http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40661191/revisions. Please don't do that. Either delete the question and repost or leave it the way it is now and wait for another answer. If you do change it again, the question will be flagged. Sorry, but Stack doesn't like that.

Comment: So, to help you out with this and proving I'm not such a bad guy, `SELECT user FROM members WHERE group=1;` the word `group` either needs to be renamed to something other than a reserved word, or use ticks around it like this one `\`` - not to be confused with regular quotes like this `'` which won't work; use ticks `\``.

Answer (score 1):

When you use **keywords** or **reserved words** don't forget to add quotes or brackets.

```
SELECT [user] FROM members WHERE [admin]=1;

SELECT [user] FROM members WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: they're using MySQL not MSSQL as per a comment they left up there *"that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax"*

Comment: *"When you use keywords or reserved words"* - Those aren't even keywords or reserved words in MySQL nor MSSQL.

Comment: Check SQL reserved wordsHe obviously use some framework.

Comment: I stand corrected on `user`. In MySQL it's a keyword yes, but not reserved https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html therefore no further action need to be taken. There is no `(R)` next to it.

Comment: The OP is using MySQL @Deadsheep39

Comment: For example admin and user in drupal both reserved. In mssql admin future reserved, user reserved keyword. In mysql user keyword...

Comment: Drupal is not a database. "MSSQL ADMIN"??? What the heck @Deadsheep39 - you're all over the place and your syntax above is completely wrong for MySQL, which this question is about.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the confusion everyone, my fault. I did this and it works.

```
SELECT user FROM members WHERE members.group=2;
```

Comment: That works because you have chosen the `database.column` syntax which is perfectly valid in MySQL where `group` (being a MySQL reserved word) does not need to be ticked.

Comment: However, this answer does not match the original question here where I had to rollback to a previous revision. You should have just deleted the question instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried to edit the question. I didn't want to delete it, but if you think that's best I will.

Comment: I think you should since it will only confuse others. What you originally posted with 2 lines of code and no php to support the question (that I removed the tag for in an edit), made the question unclear and was voted to close as such. Everything needs to be clear for everyone ;-)

Comment: You know you can flag to a moderator to make a request to delete the question. You may not have deleted it because of the given answers. Flagging your question to mods will most likely take care of that.

Comment: I flagged this 2 days ago

Comment: Ah ok. Well, give it time. They may be busy with some other more pressing issues ;-)